# Can Python expand the "*.html" pattern into the list of all matching filenames,using Windows CMD?

Tags: cmd, python-3.5

I use CMD to run Python scripts, as the following:

```
C:\Users python babynames.py --summaryfile baby*.html
```

The outcome is:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'baby*.html'
```

What to use to get the list of all matching file names?

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 modules that can help with that:

- [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html)
- [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib)

the relevant function in `pathlib` is also called [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob).

here is an example how you could use `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('/home/someuser/tmp')
for file in path.glob('*.html'):
    print(file)
# -> /home/someuser/tmp/test.html
```

Comment: I could make it on IDLE. But I want to use '*html' in CMD of window as using command line arguments, how should I do for that?

Comment: you can access command line arguments with `sys.argv`. then it depends how your windows shell treats wildcards... you'd have to test that (i can't; not on windows...).

Comment: Thank you. It seems that cmd can't identify that, though * means 0 or more occurrences of the pattern to its left in 're' module.